# JavaScript error with eventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting an error which I'm not quite sure what to make of. Anyway, before I go on to that, I found out about Unobtrusive JavaScript, at first I was just going to add an "OnClick" to my HTML but then found out that isn't a very good thing to do.

Anyway, so I did that and turned up with this code which isn't quite finished yet, but I wanted to try it out anyway before I went in and made any other changes.

```
    window.onload = function findSubmitButton(){
    var button = document.getElementsByClass("send_info").addEventListener("click", retrieveInputText());
}   

function retrieveInputText(){
    var inputArray = document.querySelectorAll("#container_id input[type=text]");
    var finalArray;
    for (var i in inputArray){
        if(inputArray[i].type == "text"){
            finalArray.push(i);
        }
    alert("done");
    }
}
```

The error chrome's console gives me is this: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionfindInputs.js:5 findSubmitButton`

There was also something I wanted to know, I want to be able to use this script with any other sort of input form, so instead of directly identifying the button for this page, I used a class identifier, this way, it works with any page. The only way there would be any issues would be if I had two buttons of the sort, as it is right now, any page with that sort of information only has one button for such procedures. I would appreciate if someone helped me out with this, I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Hard to tell where you're getting the error, but you're doing one really bad practice in JavaScript. You're using `for-in` to iterate an array (actually an array-like object). Use a typical `for` loop. `for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {...`

Comment: ...and your error messages says you it's coming from a function called `findInputs`, which doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: I see, I'm new at this and no one is really formally teaching it to me, so I have to pick it up as I go. I will use a typical for loop then. findInputs is supposed to be the file name. I'm using this externally, so that I can reuse it in any sort of form that might come up elsewhere. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByClassName(), returns an array, not an element so it does not have the `addEventListener` method, also you need to pass a function reference

```
window.onload = function findSubmitButton() {
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("send_info")[0].addEventListener("click", retrieveInputText);
}
```

Also you need to initialize the array `var finalArray = [];`

---

```
window.onload = function findSubmitButton() {
    var button = document.querySelector(".send_info").addEventListener("click", retrieveInputText);
}

function retrieveInputText() {
    var inputArray = document.querySelectorAll("#container_id input[type=text]");
    var finalArray = [];
    for (var i in inputArray) {
        if (inputArray[i].type == "text") {
            finalArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    alert("done:" + finalArray);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lyms1fer/)

Comment: It's still generating an error, tried both ways, even the what that other guy had said. Doesn't work and it still throws that error.